# How to sort and limit with NSPredicate in CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I want to fetch five records saved in Core Data and sorted by a `Date` type attribute named "recordingTime". 
For example, In MySql, we can simply add `limit = 5` to set a limit.
So, how to sort and limit with NSPredicate? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`sortDescriptors`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506262-sortdescriptors) and [`fetchLimit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506622-fetchlimit) property of [`NSFetchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest/) for that.

**Objective C:**

```
//Set sort
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"recordingTime" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors: @[sort]];
[request setFetchLimit:5];
```

**Swift:**

```
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "recordingTime", ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
request.fetchLimit = 5
```

Comment: @CallOfOrange Welcome mate :)